# Selecting 720p format on Nexus 7

Tags: camera, nexus-7

I have rooted, unlocked and modded my Nexus 7 with the 720p camera mod. If I go to `system/etc/media_profiles.xml`, it shows the 720p format.

The only problem is, that when I film with the default camera app, it films in 352x288. How do I select which video resolution I wish to use?

Screeny[image]

Circle button pressed[image]

Comment: Did you try changing the video resolution through the menu of of your camera? Open your camera and press the menu button

Comment: @Sid Where is the menu button? The three dots? I don't have that.

Comment: Yes. the dots. Press the one at your right corner

Comment: @Sid I don't have them. I'll edit with a screeny of my camera app open.

Comment: Then how do you exit the camera (or go back in any other app?)

Comment: Please see screeny. @sid

Comment: What does that circle at your right in your camera preview do? and I see the three dots as well. What do you mean *... I don't have them...*? just try pressing any of 'em. The menu should look like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NTj2P.png)

Comment: @Sid if I press the circle is comes up with a settings options (Time Lapse On/Off, Store Location) and a brightness setting. Attempting to get screeny now. I don't have the three vertical dots that symbol settings in most apps on my Camera app.

Comment: Try that settings button (which is at the left of the brightness button)

Comment: @Sid Brings up a dialog box with options:
 1. Time Lapse (Off)
 2. Store Location (On)

Comment: That's odd. Let's wait for ideas from others as well

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6880/discussion-between-asryael-and-sid)

Comment: I have the SAME problem. For the sake of clarification, the Nexus 7 as such does not have a Camera app, so what @Asryael has done is downloaded the `Camera Launcher` app which is the same thing I have done. Also, I tried using the `Camera JB+` app too, but that app just crashes.

Comment: @AbhishekSha I'm going to post essentially the same question on the xda forums. If I Get an answer I will repost here.

Comment: @Asryael - Please do so. I've also posted in the required thread. Here's the link to my post. Dev ID: abhishek_turbo911 http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1868962&page=30

Comment: @AbhishekSha I FIXED IT! Follow this tutorial exactly - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Idgd5q8_xlM

I will repost the text form of that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the following steps exactly.

1. Start up your Rooted and Unlocked Nexus 7.
2. Install "ES File Manager" from the Play Store.
3. Start "ES File Manager" and go to "Settings\Root Settings" and tick all boxes.
4. Go to http://d-h.st/E57 and download the file from your Nexus 7.
5. Go to your "/sdcard/Download/" folder.
6. Long press on the "media_profiles.xml.zip" file and select "Extract to".
7. Leave as default and hit "OK".
8. Go to "/sdcard/Download/media_profiles.xml/"
9. Long press on the "media_profiles_new-3fe47816232d5037339532623a9019f88d6ab143.xml" file and select "Rename".
10. Rename it as "media_profiles.xml".
11. Long press again, and select "Copy".
12. Navigate to "/etc/" and hit "Paste" in the top bar (2nd last icon)
13. Allow ES File Manager to overwrite the existing file.
14. Long press on "media_profiles.xml" and select "Properties" (Might need to scroll down).
15. Tick every single box and apply.
16. Restart and launch your camera app and select video.
17. Then hit the circle in the bottom left and hit the settings button that appears in the middle of your screen.
18. It should already read "720p HD" and you can press that to change between that and "480p".

Any questions, please do not hesitate to ask!